# Building an anki addon but it won't find notes for me in the collections

Tags: python, pyqt5, anki

I'm trying to build an addon which can look via a specific tag through all the notes in my anki collection and when it finds the tag - pull out a word from the focus field, search jisho for that word and then add the meaning from jisho into the meanings field. I have tested the web scraper and it works but I'm struggling to interact with anki.

I have written the code below based on the anki documentation

```py
def return_search(word):
    html = f"https://jisho.org/word/{word}"
    webpage = requests.get(html).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
    meanings_list = []
    meanings = soup.find_all(attrs = {"class": "meaning-meaning"})

    for count, item in enumerate(meanings):
        meanings_list.append(f"{count+1}) {item.get_text()}")

    meanings_list = '\n\n'.join(meanings_list)

    return meanings_list

def testFunction() -> None:
    ids = mw.col.find_cards("tag:jpzr")
    for _id in ids:
        note = mw.col.getNote(_id)
        meaning_list = return_search(note["Focus"])
        note["Meaning"] += meaning_list
        note.flush()

# create a new menu item, "test"
action = QAction("test", mw)
# set it to call testFunction when it's clicked
qconnect(action.triggered, testFunction)
# and add it to the tools menu
mw.form.menuTools.addAction(action)
```

I get an error on line 27 which is the

```py
note = mw.col.getNote(_id)
```

I don't know why it isn't accessing the notes correctly and anki's documentation is so lacking. This is the error message I get:

```
Caught exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aaron\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\myaddon\__init__.py", line 33, in testFunction
    note = mw.col.getNote(_id)
  File "anki\collection.py", line 309, in getNote
  File "anki\notes.py", line 34, in __init__
  File "anki\notes.py", line 40, in load
  File "anki\rsbackend_gen.py", line 350, in get_note
  File "anki\rsbackend.py", line 267, in _run_command
anki.rsbackend.NotFoundError
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a card ID to a function which searches through note IDs. Instead of

`note = mw.col.getNote(_id)`

it should be

`note = mw.col.get_card(_id).note()`

I'm also just starting out in Anki add-on writing, so this is not at all a comprehensive answer. The problem in the code above is because the integer `_id` is the *card id*, not the *note id*; the card is the thing which you really see in the app, and the note is the data entry which governs at least one card.